# Having issues with exporting and importing elements from a design system using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm having trouble using components I built and sent to npm as a package in an application. I'm using React and Typescript on that app and I keep getting this error:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `Home`.

The code I'm using for exporting these documents on index.d.ts is this:

```
import * as React from 'react'

declare module '@aaa/components' {

  interface ButtonProps {
    children: React.ReactNode
    background?: string | ColorName
    color?: string | ColorName
    borderRadius?: string
    shadowBackground?: string | ColorName
    shadowBorder?: string | ColorName
    buttonSize?: string
    [key: string]: unknown
  }

  export const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps>
}
```

And this is how I'm trying to import the component on my application:

```
import { Button } from '@aaa/components'
```

Also, this is my tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "index.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Aswell as my folder scheme:

[image: my folder scheme]

Thank you for your attention.

I tried creating a design system with a button component and put it on npm as a package so I can use on other projects of mine. I was expecting it to be imported on other applications and usable with all the props passed on the index.d.ts.